# How to implement a Definitive Media Library (ITIL DML)?

Tags: media, dml, itil

How to implement a Definitive Media Library (ITIL DML) ?

**I would like to know some way to implement a DML based on ITIL.**

Given a library of heterogeneous software the only solution that crosses my mind is to use a system file structure (with proper security and access permissions), however this seems very simple and if the library gets too big it will be hard to find software that search.

**Is there any specific software for DML?**

Comment: Your question is on topic on the [ITIL Stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89073/itil?referrer=x5X3k7r_NAmvg4ZTdjTOlw2)

Answer (score 0):

Many tools that offer CMDB management also offer DML management.  Some options for this are ServiceNow and IBM's Change and Configuration Management Database.

If you are only looking for DML functionality, a binary repository manager, such as [Sonatype Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/), provides metadata tagging, version control, and many other useful features.  Implementing a binary repository manager and proper procedures for maintaining it serves as an excellent DML solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with a file system to store software in form of completed, tested (software) configuration items which passed appropriate quality assurance test, etc. But because of the controlled it environment in ITIL, it is mandatory to establish an control structure for tracking the appropriate information of every CI or software in the DML. This records have to contain all relevant informations like version, build date, development, release date, etc. Only tested, confirmed and quality checked, and deployable CIs should be hold in this system.

Because of the extensive meta-data, some years ago, we created a DML depending on postgreSQL because the handling and management for the CIs along with the mandatory tracking (time when inserted, time and logging of access, access control, maybe licenses, etc.)  and meta-data is much easier in a sql database. Of course, we had to build the structure for the meta-data into the sql-db, but that was not too complicated and for our straightforward DML it was sufficient. Building and managing the metadata with each ci was supposedly easier for our system than installing, configuring, learning and managing a whole third-party DML/CML system. A caveat is when we had to save whole system images from deployed, tested, already integrated and checked systems because their size were several hundreds of GB (With the newest DB-versions, this should now also be possible, the question is, if it is useful within a SQL-DB) . But we stored the disk-images on separate disks and tracked the meta-data in our tailored DML-system (our postgreSQL) along with the information where to access it.

The advantage was, that we could easily duplicate the DML and take it for example to customer, where we only had to set up or run our (postges-based) DML and were able to access all relevant CIs we needed to set up an heterogeneous network of the target system.

In other cases, maybe it is easier to rely on already existing third party solution, but the idea of a DML can be fulfilled with every storage system as long as the appropriate proecedures, meta-data, informations and access points to the overall life-cycle management are provided and maintained.

regards